# JQuery loading inside html file but not in linked javascript file (JqueryUI tabs)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, events

I'm currently having a weird problem.

I'm using JqueryUI tabs, and am loading php pages with each tabs. This works well for me, but what I am trying to do, is loading another php page from within one of those tabs with the html "a" tag. For some reason, it doesn't work when I place the click function in a already linked javascript file, but works when I place the code in a script tag directly in the html file.

Here is the function:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.commandsRecep').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(this.href,'','width=700,height=700');
    });
})
```

I know that loading pages from within a tab is done by Ajax and am wondering if that's what causing me problems.

The link is inside a table :

```
<td><a class="commandsRecep" href="./Ben_test/page_principale.php">R&eacute;ception des commandes</a></td>
```

Comment: What is the order of includes?

Answer (score 0):

What is the order of includes?
**Make sure that jquery is included before javascript file.**

The order should be like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Done right in the html file that contains the tabs :<script src="Ben_test/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="Ben_test/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
  <script src="Ben_test/mon_script.js"></script> But I am not sure because I had to link to "mon_script.js" back in the php loaded with the tab...

Comment: Currently not looking at the log but I can say that I need the script file for something else in the page and it works

Comment: After checking the log, no errors found. Tested again and it worked that time around... weird thing

Comment: have you included jquery.js first?

Comment: Plz look at my first comment as I did, haven't changed anything except revert the code back in my script file instead of the html file and it just kinda worked

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
After a while, I got to the same type of error.
What I had to do was separate my script in two parts, one that required jqueryUI and one that didn't.
That way, in the html files where I don't import jqueryUI, I only import the one that doesn't require it.
Looks like having jquery that required jqueryUI without having imported jqueryUI was stopping the script from executing.